# Searching past mysql queries in the cli interpreter

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface, oh-my-zsh

Is there a way to quickly search the mysql interpreter for statements?

I'm think of something like ohmyzsh and bash where if I type the first few letters and then use the up and down arrows, I can quickly scroll through past commands.

For example, `mysql> sele` and then the up arrow would produce the last select query, `select fooId from FooBar`.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the UP arrow or CTRL-R?

Comment: Ctrl-R works. Thanks!